# ldap_bind() - Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, ldap, centos, lamp, openldap

I have a VM running CentOS 7 with the LAMP stack installed. On the VM I am trying to create an LDAPS connection to my domain controller which is a Windows 2008 R2 VM. The SSL certificate that I am using is self-signed and the CA has been added to the CentOS 7 CA trust.

I am able to connect to the domain controller via ldapsearch. With ldapsearch debugging level set to 1, I am able to verify that my certificate is valid.

```
ex.) ldapsearch -H "ldaps://server.ad.com" -D "domain\user-name" -W -d 1
```

Whenever I try to use LDAPS via php, I receive ldap_connect() as success but the ldap_bind() always errors with -1 Can't contact LDAP server. Below is a code example:

```
<?php

define(LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE,0x0032);
echo "defined LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE <br />";

$handle = ldap_connect("ldaps://server.ad.com:636");
echo "called ldap_connect <br />";
$errorCode = ldap_errno( $handle );
echo "error code: $errorCode <br />";
$errorMsg = ldap_error( $handle );
echo "error message: $errorMsg <br />";

if (!$handle)
{
    echo "ldap_connect method returned null <br />";
}
else
{
    echo "ldap_connect returned a handle! <br />";
}

$bind = ldap_bind($handle, 'domain\user', 'password');
echo "called ldap_bind <br />";
$errorCode2 = ldap_errno( $handle );
echo "error code: $errorCode2 <br />";
$errorMsg2 = ldap_error( $handle );
echo "error message: $errorMsg2 <br />";

if (!$bind)
{
    echo "ldap_bind method returned null <br />";
}
else
{
    echo "ldap_bind returned a bind! <br />";
}

if(ldap_get_option($handle, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error))
{
    echo "Error binding to LDAP: $extended_error";
}
else
{
    echo "Error bind to LDAP: No additional information is available.";
}   
?>
```

Output:

```
defined LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE
called ldap_connect
error code: 0
error message: Success
ldap_connect returned a handle!
called ldap_bind
error code: -1
error message: Can't contact LDAP server
ldap_bind method returned null
Error bind to LDAP: No additional information is available.
```

I feel like the "Can't contact LDAP server" is too generic of an error message, so I tried to add the LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-bind.php -first comment). But this does not seem to work.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I found that running this PHP file via command line would bind successfully. It was only failing when viewing it from a browser.

With this information, I was able to ask another question on ServerFault and discovered that this bind is actually failing because of SELinux configuration.

Please see full answer here:https://serverfault.com/questions/677013/php-executes-with-different-results-in-command-line-than-when-browsed-to-in-apac